# How to use typescript Path aliases in Cucumber?

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I need to use Cucumber in a project that uses path aliasing. As soon as I would import one of the path aliased modules, I get an error

I have tried solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806211/10786737), but I am running into another problem: Whenever I use the

```
   --require-module tsconfig-paths/register \
```

part, I suddenly get

```
    TypeError: cucumber_1.Given is not a function
```

error whenever I try to run the features.

(The error changes to 
    `TypeError: Given is not a function`
 when I use the `const { Given } = require('cucumber')` syntax)

Is there any other solution for path aliasing in Cucumber, or is there a fix to the `is not a function` problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using `cucumber.js` file at root as config, which was interfering with `tsconfig-paths/register`: `tsconfig` then picked up the `cucumber.js` file for `from 'cucumber'`, instead of the cucumber module.

So the fix is to write all the `--require-module` options to the command line instead